# Possible MAC design

Tags: authentication, mac, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

### The problem

Let the following be a family of PRF functions with key length $2\lambda$
$$\mathbb{F} = \{F_k:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^n\}_{k\in\{0,1\}^{2\lambda}}$$
Assuming one way functions exists, show how to use $\mathbb{F}$ to construct a secure MAC with key length $\lambda$ bits and message length $t*n$ bits for any $t\in\mathbb{N}$.

### My solution

Assuming we have one way functions, then we have PRG. Assume $G:\{0,1\}^\lambda\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{2\lambda}$ we can construct
$$F'(k,m) = F_{G(k)}(m_1)\oplus ...\oplus F_{G(k)}(m_t)$$ where $m = m_1...m_t$ and $\forall i \; m_i\in\{0,1\}^n$

Comment: Compare the values of the MACs for $m_1\Vert m_2$ and $m_2\Vert m_1$.

Comment: Ok i see it now, we can use the same idea of CBC-MAC, but given that the PRF has lenght $2\lambda$ we need just to stretch the key of $F'$ using a PRG. Am i right?

Comment: @zBION1C yes, correct